# I've been trying to contact you for days but you seem to be very ____________

Tags: exam-questions

Which option fits best in the following sentence?

> I've been trying to contact you for days but you seem to be very ___________.

1. inaccessible
2. elusive
3. evasive

The answer is either 1 or 2 for me. But the answer is 1. But I read the word  elusive is used in a sense for people who hard to contact or reach. So I don't know why we cannot use the word elusive in this sentence.

Comment: Both "elusive" and "evasive" imply that the person is intentionally avoiding contact, whereas "inaccessible" does not. Could that be the reason?

Comment: @AndySchweig it could be.

Comment: In the case of "contact", inaccessible is better in the sense that "can't be reached" does not imply physical movement. *elusive* or *evasive* are more about physical movement to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying someone is either **elusive** or **evasive** implies they are purposely avoiding you for some reason.  Usually it is not a nice things to say, more diplomatic would be

> ...you seem *( very )* inaccessible.
>   ...you seem very busy.

Deer will be **elusive** or **evasive** to stay away from hunters.

Comment: Sometimes a short phrase works better than a single word. _I've been trying to contact you for days but you've been **hard to reach**._

Comment: @J.R. +1 and also **you seemed to have disappeared**.